How to add metadata (exif) to the generated blob from canvas and download it using fileSaver
I have a project in Angular and I generate a map image in canvas using OpenLayers, then I download it locally with the extension .png/.tiff using fileSaver. How can I add metadata to the downloaded file (blob) to include, for example, coordinates?
mapCanvas.toBlob(blob => {
        fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'example.png');
      });

Tried with various npm exif libraries but they mainly have methods for reading.

Does this answer your question? Is it possible to modify the exif data of an image taken from Canvas in HTML5?

I'll check it out and if it solves my problem, I'll delete this question

Sure you didn't forget? Otherwise edit your Q to outline why it would not solve your problem.

The solution does not work and applies to jpg files

And with exif-library instead (which was forked off piexifjs to support PNG)? This time include your attempts into your question by editing it.
